# Removing channel(s) from a user while deleting

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I've found myself in a situation where I have users that subscribe to various things to receive notifications. That all works great when it's the user himself subscribing and unsubscribing from the channels. I run into an issue when I want to delete a user and restrict him access to one of those channels. I'm writing my app for iOS and have realized that editing another devices PFInstallation is a no go. What really needs to happen is when an admin decides to delete a user from his group of notifications, some code is run before the deletion to ensure this user will no longer receive notifications for that group.

It's broken down like this:
There are different departments (fire departments). Each has a certain number of types of notifications (ex. fire, ems, chief, all)... So the user can enable / disable channels for each of these (the channel is a combination of the notification type and the objectid of the dept; ex: fire_abc123). The user will most likely have multiple departments so simply deleting the installation or clearing the channel array wouldn't be the best option.

Unfortunately, there's really no code I can post because I haven't figured out how to quite do this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using cloud code to accomplish this. If you cannot edit other devices installations in your code, you can `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` in a cloud code function to modify them. The function would find the installation that the user you want to remove is linked to, and remove a certain channel from that installation.